# Bars position in ggplot2

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

I'm making a graph using `ggplot` and I am not able to reduce the spaces between the bars. I can only do this by increasing the size of the bars, but I would like them to become thin and not so far away.

I've used the `position_dodge(width = 0.5)` but did not help me.

My Script

```
library(scales)
seguro <- matrix(0,4,3)
seguro <- as.data.frame(seguro)
seguro[,1] <- c("2010","2011","2012","2013")
seguro[,2] <-c(89,86,87,88)
seguro[,3] <-c("89%","86%","87%","88%")
names(seguro)[c(1)]<-c("Ano")
ggplot(seguro, aes(Ano, V2, fill=Ano))+
         geom_bar(width=0.3,stat="identity",
                 position="identity", aes(fill=Ano)) +
         scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) +
         geom_text(data=seguro,aes(x=Ano,label=V3),vjust=0)
```

Comment: Something like `+ coord_equal(1/7)` is one option.

Comment: this changed the Y coordinate, but I want to decrease the space between the bars in X

Comment: It did reduce the space between the bars. Get a ruler and measure it. If you reduce the space between the bars without shortening the y axis, you'll end up with an enormous amount of blank space in your plot on the left and right.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're question is better answered by changing the output window size, not tweaking code in  your `ggplot` function:

```
library(scales)
seguro <- matrix(0,4,3)
seguro <- as.data.frame(seguro)
seguro[,1] <- c("2010","2011","2012","2013")
seguro[,2] <-c(89,86,87,88)
seguro[,3] <-c("89%","86%","87%","88%")
names(seguro)[c(1)]<-c("Ano")

x11(height=7,width=5)

ggplot(seguro, aes(Ano, V2, fill=Ano))+
         geom_bar(width=0.3,stat="identity",
                 position="identity", aes(fill=Ano)) +
         scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) +
         geom_text(data=seguro,aes(x=Ano,label=V3),vjust=0)
```

You can do similar things if you are outputting it as a pdf or jpeg:

```
pdf("test.pdf",height=7,width=5)
ggplot(seguro, aes(Ano, V2, fill=Ano))+
         geom_bar(width=0.3,stat="identity",
                 position="identity", aes(fill=Ano)) +
         scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) +
         geom_text(data=seguro,aes(x=Ano,label=V3),vjust=0)
dev.off()
```